# nashorn CompiledScript graalvm equivalent

Tags: graalvm

I have a fairly big file that needs to often be evaluated,

with nashorn I used to do something like that :

```
CompiledScript compiledScript = ((Compilable) engine).compile(text);
```

and later on, I could call many times the following :

```
Context context = new SimpleScriptContext();
compiledScript.eval(context);
```

this was quite fast.

Using the new Polyglot API, I do :

```
Source source = Source.newBuilder("js", myFile).build();
```

then :

```
Context context = Context.newBuilder("js").option("js.nashorn-compat", "true").build();
context.eval(source)
```

Using jmh, I have a big performance difference between the two

```
Benchmark                     Mode  Cnt   Score    Error  Units
JmhBenchmark.testEvalGraal    avgt    5  42,855 ± 11,118  ms/op
JmhBenchmark.testEvalNashorn  avgt    5   2,739 ±  1,101  ms/op
```

If I do the `eval` on the same context, it is working properly, but I don't want to have a shared context between two consecutive `eval` (unless the concept of Context of Graal is not the same as the one from Nashorn).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To reproduce your `ScriptEngine` setup with GraalVM, you should re-use the same `Engine` (`org.graalvm.polyglot.Engine`) and `.close()` the context after use:

```
Source source = Source.newBuilder("js", myFile).build();
Engine engine = Engine.create();
```

and later:

```
Context context = Context.newBuilder("js")
                         .engine(engine)
                         .option("js.nashorn-compat", "true").build();
context.eval(source);
context.close();
```

Quoting the `Context.Builder.engine` [documentation](https://www.graalvm.org/sdk/javadoc/org/graalvm/polyglot/Context.Builder.html#engine-org.graalvm.polyglot.Engine-):

> Explicitly sets the underlying engine to use. By default, every context has its own isolated engine. If multiple contexts are created from one engine, then they may share/cache certain system resources like ASTs or optimized code by specifying a single underlying engine.

Comment: Thank you. One addition, I was also missing the `context.close()`. Without it, I did not see any performance improvement (even with re-using the same Engine).